# read items from listbox

Tags: c#, listbox, streamreader

I have a listbox with 1 or more textfiles, which im going to print as commands.
but I dont know how to make the streamreader read from listbox ?

so far I got this.:

```
public void OutputBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDocument PrintD = new PrintDocument();
    PrintD.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.PrintDocument_PrintPage);
    StreamReader SR = new StreamReader("C:\\myfile.txt");
    PrintD.Print();

}
```

is there enyway I can change "C:\myfile.txt" or do I have to use "foreach" ?

Comment: ps. in my code, I assumed that the ID of your Listbox is `lb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this? I don't fully understand the question

```
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\temp\\").Where(p => 
                                 p.EndsWith(".txt")).ToArray<string>();
foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
{
    lb.Items.Add(new ListItem(fileName, fileName);
}
```

Ok so you have the listbox filled with filenames?

```
private StreamReader sr;

public void OutputBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(var li in lb.Items)
    {
        PrintDocument PrintD = new PrintDocument();
        PrintD.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.PrintDocument_PrintPage);
        sr = new StreamReader(li.ToString());
        PrintD.Print();        
    }
}

private void PrintDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev) 
{
     float linesPerPage = 0;
     float yPos =  0;
     int count = 0;
     float leftMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Left;
     float topMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Top;
     String line = null;

     // Calculate the number of lines per page.
     linesPerPage = ev.MarginBounds.Height  / 
        printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics) ;

     // Iterate over the file, printing each line.
     while (count < linesPerPage && ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)) 
     {
        yPos = topMargin + (count * printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics));
        ev.Graphics.DrawString (line, printFont, Brushes.Black, 
           leftMargin, yPos, new StringFormat());
        count++;
     }

     // If more lines exist, print another page.
     if (line != null) 
        ev.HasMorePages = true;
     else 
        ev.HasMorePages = false;
}
```

Comment: my Listbox contains a list of filenames. I want all of those to be read by the streamreader and then to be printed out.
btw. i cant get the ListItem to work. :S

Comment: yeah well. i cant find ListItem :(

Comment: is it winforms, webforms or wpf? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx

Comment: i believe winforms because of your response http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items.aspx so you can iterate over the items by replacing ListItem with var or string.

Comment: yes its win Forms.

ok.. something happend this time, thanks to your code... But
when hitting my OutputBtn. it prints a blank document and not the item in my listbox

Comment: @MikkelEriksen a blank page is caused by your `PrintDocument_PrintPage` method. please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.print.aspx for that issue

Comment: ok.i'll read on that. but thanks for your help, you've gave me a great start :D